# Use source from Git to run a website

Tags: git, laravel, web, bitbucket

Is there any way, to run website, using source from Git?

For example,
I have private repository in Bitbucket, and I want to use this source in my website automatically (so the source will be automatically downloaded on my server) and when I make changes in repository (for example, update any file), the source is automatically updated in my webisite.

In this case, I want to use Laravel.

Thank you.

Comment: Heroku is updated with git.

Comment: Sure, it's possible.  And a lot has already been written on this topic.  Where you have looked so far?  What didn't work out?

Comment: Does bitbucket have hooks?

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/envoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for are webhooks. Webhooks allow for a git command to be executed automatically when a specific task is done, such as a 'git push' to your repository.

In your instance a webhook could be set up to execute a script on your server to run a 'git pull' command. Here's the documentation that Bitbucket provides on the subject - https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Webhooks

Comment: You will also need an endpoint. This is a tutorial I starred a while back. It is pretty complete and includes instructions for Bitbucket. https://gist.github.com/oodavid/1809044

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this if you have git installed on the target machine by using a post-receive hook.

1. Repository init (instructions are for Linux)

   - Create a user called git.
   - mkdir /var/repo/your_name.git
   - cd to that dir.
   - Run git init --bare

     2. Create post-receive to push files to /var/www/your_site
   - cd hooks
   - Create post-receive:
   - `#!/bin/sh git --work-tree=/var/www/your_site --git-dir=/var/repo/your_name.git checkout -f sudo /usr/local/bin/post-receive-your_site`

     3. Change ownership of files in /var/www to web.web (the owner/group of the html dir).  Since this runs as git, you need to allow special sudo on the script, which means putting it in one of the safe directories, i.e.
        /usr/local/bin.
   - Create post-receive-your_name: 
     `#!/bin/sh find /var/www/your_site/ -type f -group 'git' -exec chown web:web {} \;      find /var/www/your_site/ -type d -group 'git' -exec chown web:web {} \;`
   - As root: 
     `cd /usr/local/bin`
     `ln -s /var/repo/your_name.git/hooks/post-receive-your_site`
     vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config and add "AllowUsers YOUR_SSH_ID git
     vi sudoadd: git ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/post-receive-your_site

     After setting the repository up, you'll need to `git remote add live <YOUR NEW REPOS>`, and then you can push to production by running `git push live master`.